# Property within an array not being read by a function - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, dynamic, business-catalyst

I am having some trouble. I am working within Business Catalyst which stores dynamic user-submitted data and allows me to output it in whatever way I need.

I have created a series of Web Apps that work together to allow users to take quizzes. Currently I am receiving an error message 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'questionText' of undefined'

How my code is working currently:

1. A user submits a form with quiz/survey data.
2. They are directed to a new page that runs a search for the most recent quiz/survey submission unique to their user.
3. The data is output on the page within a div.
4. A function reads the data and builds the page content accordingly to display the correct quiz/survey results.

The data that is submitted is output in the following format. Note that the {tags} are Business Catalysts way of outputting dynamic information - the {tag} is replaced with the user-submitted data on the page. Also note that I have only shown the data for 3 questions, there are up to 15 in total.

```
var quizSurvey = "{tag_quiz/survey}";
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    function Question(questionNumber, questionText, answerType, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctAnswer, userMultichoice, userTF, userSRating, userSSAnswer, qPassFail) {
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.answerType = answerType;
        this.answerA = answerA;
        this.answerB = answerB;
        this.answerC = answerC;
        this.answerD = answerD;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        this.userMultichoice = userMultichoice;
        this.userTF = userTF;
        this.userSRating = userSRating;
        this.userSSAnswer = userSSAnswer;
        this.qPassFail = qPassFail;
    };
    var question = new Array();
question[1] = new Question("1", "{tag_q1-question}", "{tag_q1-answer-type}", "{tag_q1-multichoice-a}", "{tag_q1-multichoice-b}", "{tag_q1-multichoice-c}", "{tag_q1-multichoice-d}", "{tag_q1-correct-answer}", "{tag_q-multichoice-1}", "{tag_q-t/f-1}", "{tag_s-ratings-1}", "{tag_s-shortanswer-1}", "{tag_q1-pass/fail}");
question[2] = new Question("2", "{tag_q2-question}", "{tag_q2-answer-type}", "{tag_q2-multichoice-a}", "{tag_q2-multichoice-b}", "{tag_q2-multichoice-c}", "{tag_q2-multichoice-d}", "{tag_q2-correct-answer}", "{tag_q-multichoice-2}", "{tag_q-t/f-2}", "{tag_s-ratings-2}", "{tag_s-shortanswer-2}", "{tag_q2-pass/fail}");
question[3] = new Question("3", "{tag_q3-question}", "{tag_q3-answer-type}", "{tag_q3-multichoice-a}", "{tag_q3-multichoice-b}", "{tag_q3-multichoice-c}", "{tag_q3-multichoice-d}", "{tag_q3-correct-answer}", "{tag_q-multichoice-3}", "{tag_q-t/f-3}", "{tag_s-ratings-3}", "{tag_s-shortanswer-3}", "{tag_q3-pass/fail}");
    var userScore = "{tag_total score}";
    var passingScore = "{tag_required score to pass}";
    var showAnswers = "{tag_show answers}";
```

So now that you see how the Data is stored, here is the code for the page that it is output on. Note that I left out Step 2, the code that runs the search - I know this works, so I didn't think you would need to see it.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="quiz-survey-search" id="qs-results" style="display: block;">&nbsp;{module_webappscustomer,19627,l,,,_self,true,1,true,1} </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="correct" id="correct" style="display: none;">
        <h2 id="quiz-headline-1" style="line-height:110%;margin-bottom:1rem;"></h2>
        <h4 style="text-align:center;margin:1.5rem 3rem;color:black!important;">Good work completing this chapter!<br />
            Your score is:</h4>
        <div class="large-score" id="score-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="incorrect" id="incorrect" style="display: none;">
        <h2 id="quiz-headline-2" style="line-height:110%;margin-bottom:1rem;"></h2>
        <h4 style="text-align:center;margin:1.5rem 3rem;color:black!important;">You did not achieve the required passing score. Please review the materials and take the quiz again to complete this chapter.</h4>
        <div class="large-score" id="score-2" style="margin:3rem 0rem;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="survey" id="survey" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Thank you for completing the survey.</h2>
            <h4>Your answers have been submitted.</h4></div>
</div>
<div id="correct-answers" style="display: none;">
    <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;">Correct Answers</h3>
    <p style="font-weight: bold;">Although you passed the quiz you had one or more answers that were incorrect.
        Below are the correct answers.</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="incorrectQuestions"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script>
var quizsurveyDiv = document.getElementById('qs-results').innerHTML;
if (quizsurveyDiv == "&nbsp;") {
    var element = '{module_url,AllIDs}';
    var arrayOfStrings = element.split("-");
    document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_206').value = arrayOfStrings[0];
    document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_2').value = arrayOfStrings[1];
    document.getElementById('CAT_Custom_3').value = arrayOfStrings[2];
    catcustomcontentform9225.submit();
} else {
    if (quizSurvey == "Quiz") {
        var qNumber = 0;
        var qNumbers = function() {
            for (i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
                if (question[i].questionText !== "") {
                    qNumber = qNumber + 1;
                    console.log('here - ' + qNumber);
                };
            };
        };
        var writeDivs = function() {
            var incorrectQDiv = "";
            for (i = 1; i <= qNumber; i++) {
                if (question[i].qPassFail == "0") {
                    incorrectQDiv =  document.getElementById('incorrectQuestions').innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById('incorrectQuestions').innerHTML = incorrectQDiv + "<div class='small-12 medium-6 columns incorrectQ' id='incorrectQ-" + question[i].questionNumber + "'>Hi!!</div>";
                    console.log('here2 - ' + qNumber);
                } else if (question[i].qPassFail == "1") {
            };
        };
        };
        var writeQContent = function() {
            for (var i = 1; i <= qNumber; i++) {
                if (question[i].qPassFail == "0") {
                    if (question[i].answerType == "True/False") {
                        var qUserAnswer = question[i].userTF;
                    } else {
                        qUserAnswer = question[i].userMultichoice;
                    };
                    document.getElementById('incorrectQ-' + question[i].questionNumber).innerHTML = "<p><span class='pinkNum'>" + question[i].questionNumber + "</span>" + question[i].questionText + '</p><div class="row"><div class="small-12 small-push-12 medium-6 columns"><p><span class="pink-title">Your Answer: ' + qUserAnswer + '</span><br/><div id="incorrectA-' + question[i].questionNumber + '"></div></p></div><div class="small-12 small-pull-12 medium-6 columns"><p><span class="pink-title">Correct Answer: ' + question[i].correctAnswer + '</span><div id="correctA-' + question[i].questionNumber + '"></div></p></div></div>';
                };
                if (question[i].qPassFail == "0" && question[i].answerType == "Multiple Choice") {
                    var correctADiv = "correctA-" + question[i].questionNumber; console.log(correctADiv);
                    if (question[i].correctAnswer == "A") {
                        document.getElementById(correctADiv).innerHTML = question[i].answerA;
                    } else if (question[i].correctAnswer == "B") {
                        document.getElementById(correctADiv).innerHTML = question[i].answerB;
                    } else if (question[i].correctAnswer == "C") {
                        document.getElementById(correctADiv).innerHTML = question[i].answerC;
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById(correctADiv).innerHTML = question[i].answerD;
                    }; 
                };
            };
        };
        var showTheAnswers = function() {
            if (quizPassFail == "1") {
                document.getElementById('quiz-headline-1').innerHTML = "You passed the quiz: " + quizName;
                document.getElementById('score-1').innerHTML = '<span class="large-score">' + totalScore + '%</span>';
                document.getElementById('correct').style.display = "block";
                if (showAnswers == "1") {
                    if (totalScore != "100") {
                document.getElementById('correct-answers').style.display = "block";
                } else if (showAnswers != "1" || totalScore == "100") {
                    document.getElementById('correct-answers').style.display = "none";
                    }; 
                };
            } else {
                document.getElementById('quiz-headline-2').innerHTML = "Unfortunately you did not pass the quiz: " + quizName ;
                document.getElementById('score-2').innerHTML = '<div class="hide-for-small medium-1 large-2 columns"> &nbsp;</div><div class="small-6 medium-5 large-4 columns"><p><span class="large-score" id="userScore"></span><br/>Your Score</p></div><div class="small-6 medium-5 large-4 columns"><p><span class="large-score" id="requiredScore"></span><br />Required Score</p></div><div class="hide-for-small medium-1 large-2 columns"> </div>';
                innerScores();
                document.getElementById('incorrect').style.display = "block";
            };
        };
        var innerScores = function() {
            document.getElementById('userScore').innerHTML = totalScore + "%";
            document.getElementById('requiredScore').innerHTML = requiredScore + "%";
                            console.log('innerScores');
        }; 
        if (showAnswers == "1" && totalScore != "100") {
            qNumbers();
            writeDivs();
            writeQContent();
            showTheAnswers();
        } else if (showAnswers == "0" && totalScore != "100") {
            showTheAnswers();
        } else {
            showTheAnswers();
        }
    } else if (quizSurvey == "Survey") {
        document.getElementById('survey').style.display = "block";
    };
    courseCompletePass();
};
```

Thank you for any and all possible help. This has been an extremely difficult coding process and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No-one is going to debug a few hundred lines of code. Please provide a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I have cut down as much as I can. I can remove the div content where everything is output, but the rest of the information is absolutely needed.

And if I take out the div content it's 94 lines of code - hardly several hundred.

Comment: Any chance your problem is that your loop in `qNumbers` goes up to 14, but you only have 3 questions? Or that your array doesn't have a `0` indexed-value (you start with `questions[1] = ...` but your loop starts with `i = 0`)? What line do you see the error on?

Comment: That was it! Thank you apsillers!!